# Can I access mysql or oracle in EF 7 I heard EF is only way to access DB

Tags: entity-framework

Can I access mysql or oracle in asp.net-vnext? I heard EF is only way to access DB.Any Nuget package available for mysql,oracle etc..

Comment: It's not even out yet, it's far too early to ask whether Oracle will release providers for Oracle and MySQL. The current developoment state is described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/12/02/ef7-priorities-focus-and-initial-release.aspx)

Comment: Yes not yet completed the development of asp.net-vnext.I am trying to compare with old asp.net development also analyzing the possibilities.

Comment: Then you are comparing different things. Entity framework isn't part of ASP.NET nor are there any dependencies between them. You can use ASP.NET vNext with EF6 if you want. Or use NHibernate, Dapper, ADO.NET or any other data access library you like

Answer (score 1):

While EF7 is under development and anything I say is subject to change, I can tell you this much from the official description on [EF 7 Github page](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/What-is-EF7-all-about)

> EF7 is a lightweight and extensible version of Entity Framework that enables new platforms and new data stores. Starting with EF7, Windows Phone, Windows Store, ASP.NET 5, and traditional desktop application can all now take advantage of Entity Framework. In addition to relational databases, EF7 also supports non-relational data stores such as Azure Table Storage and Redis.

The idea here is to make it more extensible and not more limiting. More likely than not, it should support what it supports currently.

Also, EF is the way that Microsoft is recommending nowadays. It certainly isn't the only way. In order for it to be the only way Microsoft might have to modify the accessibility of the ADO.NET classes that are part of the .NET framework. And that's definitely not happening.

Comment: I'd add to this that Entity Framework is simply a pluggable ORM.  When an entity (person, group, company etc) wants to allow access to a database using EF, they simply need to write there own [EF Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee789835(v=vs.100).aspx) ([Oracle's for example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-sep/o51odt-453447.html)).  If you're lucky you'll see a Beta/ctp of the provider for these database's before EF is officially released, otherwise you'll have to wait.

Comment: Thanks , this give me more idea on data access in asp.net-vnext.